# nodeJS script instance for every user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

Probably I haven't understood nodeJS at all, but I build a running client and server app, which sends data trough socket.io.

It works perfectly, but when I open the site on another machine, the content is identically.

When using PHP, every machine running the script has a unique instance of it, so I can make database calls that are only visible to the particular user.

Hopefully this is understandable.

EDIT:

Let's say I've got a normal socket.io setup.
When clicking a button, the following is fired.

```
socket.emit('getImages', 'someData');
```

this will make the server send 2 images back, which I will then display on the site.

This works fine for one user. But if there are multiple users at the same time, the images will get changed on every user's site, not just on the one, which fired the function.

Comment: What are you talking about? Are you looking for session state?

Comment: Node works somewhat the same way as PHP, you can do database calls for the current user in the callbacks for the route etc.

Comment: Look at this simple framework on nodejs it provide a simple web server, http://expressjs.com/

Comment: edited the question, should be more clear now.

Comment: @ArEsiiX I quess that on your server you simply emit to all connected clients. Obviously not what you want. So you need to make sure you only emit to the client that sent socket.emit('getImages'... That's quite easy to do.

Comment: @Molda yep, one callback function and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: It is *possible* to use Node in a CGI-style configuration (one process/simulated process per request) like PHP traditionally is, but it's extremely rare. Using a persistent process is generally much more efficient (it took a lot of work to make PHP perform reasonably well like that), and the shared state is frequently considered a benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server:

```
socketServer.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("A Client has connected.");
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("A Client has disconnected.");
    });
    socket.on('getImages', function(data){
        //Do something with the image/data here
        //send something to the socket that emitted getimages command
        this.emit.('commandhere', datahere);
        /* you can also do this.broadcast.emit('commandhere', datahere) to broadcast
        all connected sockets except the one who emitted the command
        or socketServer.emit('commandhere', datahere) to broadcast all connected
        sockets. */
    });
});
```